# Resilience to rogue miners

Tags: mining, security, attacks

How will Ethereum stop evil-miner attacks where a gas-guzzling tx is added to a just-solved block to slow down competition once gasLimit goes high ?

For relevant discussion see this reddit thread, however from my perspective No satisfactory answer was provided there

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3fcw0i/verifiers_dilemma_renders_ethereum_nonincentive/ctodv4k?context=3

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the question here.  Vitalik's answers in the quoted reddit thread may be the most satisfactory for a while...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent such behaviors once the `gasLimit` is large enough to affect others. I guess the only solution is to guarantee the `gasLimit` to be reasonably small for *most* of the miners. However, there is a catch. How do you know how much is small?

Comment: gasLimit is the same for all miners